# Counting word occurances in txt file, returning dictionary and converting dict to list with the help of classes

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have been given an assignment to create a program that reads a txt file, counts the occurances of the different words in that text and ultimately returns a list of the words and their number of occurances, eg. "potato" 2, by the help of a "class" with the instancevariables "word" and "number of occurances".The reason as to why I store the words and occurances in a dictionary and then convert that dictionary to a list is because the instructions tell me to base my program on this piece of code:

```
def counter (allWords):
    d = {}
    for word in allWords:
        if word in d.keys():
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else:
            d[word] = 1
    return d
```

Here is my code as of now

```
def counter (allWords):
    d = {}
    for word in allWords:
        if word in d.keys():
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else:
            d[word] = 1
    return d

infile = (input('What is the name of the file?')+'.txt')
with open(infile, encoding='utf-8') as file:
    wall_of_text = file.read()
    allWords = wall_of_text.split()

d = counter(allWords)

li = list()

def convert (d):
    for word in d.keys():
        li.append(word + " " + str(d[word]))
    return li

li = convert(d)
```

Can you help a newbie out by giving me a hint on how I would do the same thing, but with classes?

Comment: Do you *have* to use your own functions?

Comment: A `collections.Counter` dict, `word.strip(string.punctuation)` and `str.split` is all you need where word is `for line in f: for word in line.split()`

Comment: The only function that is mandatory is "def counter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class def:

```
class Word:
    def __init__(self,word):
        self.word = word
        self.occ = 1
```

Counter function:

```
def counter (allWords):
    d = {}
    for word in allWords:
        if word in d:
            d[word].occ += 1
        else:
            d[word] = Word(word)

return d.items()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Counted:
   def __init__(self,word,ct=0):       
      self.word,self.counted_occurances = word,ct
   def inc(self):
      self.counted_occurances += 1 
   def __str__(self):
      return str([self.word,self.counted_occurances])

class Counter:        
    def __init__ (self,allWords):
       d = {}
       for word in allWords:
          d.setdefault(word,Counted(word)).inc()
       self.d = d
    def __getattr__(self,attr):
       return getattr(self.d,attr)
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.d)

def counter(allwords):
    return Counter(allwords)

c =  counter("Hello World!!")
print c
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question because the Counter class lacks necessary attributes.

Comment: it has `def counter` ... oh I see fair enough after re-reading the question I agree this is not what he is looking for and your solution is actually the correct one

Comment: I mean the class doesn't have the attributes required.

Comment: its the first method in the Counter class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92088/discussion-between-ppperry-and-joran-beasley).